# Изменить caption в fancybox 3

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

Есть фотогалерея на facybox 3. Нужно под каждым фото добавить блок, который содержит текст и ссылку. Ссылка будет одинаково стилизована и иметь одинаковый href под каждой фото. 
Пробовал использовать `data-caption`, но в html это смотрится ужасно, когда много текста получается и много фото.
При помощи `'beforeLoad': function()` пытался добавить элемент, но он добавляется несколько раз.
Каким образом можно стилизовать `caption` блок, добавлять туда текст в зависимости от выбранной картинки и если описания нет, то просто оставить ссылку под фото? Либо для такой цели можно воспользоваться другим плагином?
Благодарен за помощь

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
    'beforeLoad': function(){
        $('.fancybox-caption').append('<a href="#">TEST</a>');;
    }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atomr/frqah7m2/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]